# Piecewise Function Formatting With \linespread{1.4}

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have a problem about the size of the piecewise function's paranthesis' size. I need to use \linespread{1.4} for whole document but it effects the vertical space for math equations also.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Here's my tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{1.4}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\[
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    1,&x=1 \\ 
    0,&x\in[0,1)
\end{cases}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use `\linespread{<factor>}` you need to reduce accordingly `\arraystretch` to the reciprocal of `<factor>`, so matrices will appear right. But `cases` fixes `\arraystretch` to 1.2 and you need to fix that too.

If you want more space between the lines in `cases`, you need to specify it manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\linespread{1.4}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.71423}% 1/1.4
\newcommand{\casesarraystretch}{0.85714}% *1.2
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{\casesarraystretch}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
I_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    1,&x=1 \\
    0,&x\in[0,1)
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]